# Create all possible combinations of entries from multiple lists

Tags: python, string, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have different scalar metrics that I need to take inventory of in a large repository of data. The format of one entry for a metric would look something like this:

```
{a}_{b}_{c}_{d}
            # Where ${a} = subjid, ex. "1000061"
            # Where ${b} = "ROIstats"
            # Where ${c} = statistic, [mean, median, sigma]
            # Where ${d} = modality, [AX, FA, RAD, TR]
            # EXAMPLE DOWN BELOW: 
            # {a}_{b}_{c}_{d} = 1000061_ROIstats_mean_FA
```

There should be 24 combos total (as seen below):
[image: All possible data points for one subj_ID]

I am attempting to use `itertools.product` after concatenating `{a}` and `{b}` since there is only one possible entry for both (one unique subject ID which I am getting from a list `found_subjs`, and `"ROIstats"` respectively. Is there a way I can combine `{a}, {b}, {c}, and {d}` together to capture all the points for each `{a}_{b}`?

Here is my attempt. I don't know if I need to change the formatting or put the combinations in a seperate list:

```
cs = ["mean", "median", "sigma"]
ds = ["AX", "FA", "fwAX", "fwFA", "fwRAD", "fwVF", "RAD", "TR"]   
  
for s in found_subjs:
    os.chdir("{final_destination}\\{s}".format(final_destination=final_destination, s=s))
    for c,d in product(cs, ds):
        print(s+"_"+"ROIstats"+"_"+c+"_"+d)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-7fa394581c24>", line 4, in <module>
    print(s+"_"+"ROIstats"+"_"+c+"_"+d)

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Comment: isnt that a numpy error?

Comment: Try changing your print statement to
`print(f"{s}_ROIstats_{c}_{d}")`

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide us with an [mre]. The error implies you are working with numpy objects - nothing in your example shows that.